# How to change homepage by Registry in Edge Browser

Tags: microsoft-edge

I want to change the homepage in the Edge browser via Registry but it's encrypted and I see (Protected - It is a violation of Windows Policy to modify. See aka.ms/browserpolicy) in Registry. Please help me to edit homepage in Registry or find where it's a violation of Windows policy to modify. See aka.ms/browserpolicy

Comment: Why do you want to do this through registry?

Comment: Because i want to change Search Engine in Edge and explore new Browser of Microsoft

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is only the homepage in Edge you want to set then change the URL below to your preference and then save this as a .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Main]
"HomeButtonEnabled"=dword:00000001
"HomeButtonPage"="https://www.google.com/"
```

Comment: I checked my Win10 x64, did not found such 2 keys.

Comment: @LeiYang: That's why you need to run the **.reg** file shown here (by double-clicking on it) to enter this information. If the keys are not there, they will be created. The solution works for me in Windows 10 (1607).

Answer (score 7):

ProtectedHomepages value is not really encrypted, instead it is an obfuscated buffer which contains homepages strings and the cryptographic hash for these strings. Buffer is obfuscated using the random generated seed which is also stored as a part of the buffer. I have done some reverse engineering research and published the results [here](https://www.ntkernel.com/microsoft-edge-protectedhomepages/).

So, basically, reading and decrypting this value is easier than modifying due to the required crypto-hash. However, reading capability is the only required for anti-malware software. I don't know what reasons you have to modify this value, hopefully you are not writing a piece of malware...

Comment: So, why does the hash make this so much more difficult? You just hash the decrypted payload. All you need to do is figure out which hash function was used and in fact the hash function is also somewhere around although if some standard hash was used then all you need to do is figure which one.

Answer (score -1):

Currently it is not possible to change the startpage of Microsoft Edge writing string or binary value into the registry. The entry to change is "Protected - It is a violation of Windows Policy to modify. See aka.ms/browserpolicy" -> Value "ProtectedHomepages". The value is a encrypted binary value, in which the current homepage is not readable.
When you have to set a specific homepage more than one time and you want to do it with C# here a Workaround:

Set the startpage you want via UI of the Microsoft Edge browser. After Change of it restart the browser and export the registrykey named above. Open the exported file and copy the binary data into a string constant or resource in your C# Solution. In the function to write this Setting you can copy the string into a byte-Array and than writing as binary value into the registry. This entry has effect after restart of Microsoft Edge.

The same way you should use also when you want to Change the Default Search Provider. But in this case in addition to the value "ProtectedSearchScopes" one more registrykey is to use -> "OpenSearch". This key does/should exists by third Party search Providers only. This key should be deleted or does not exist if the search Provider is Bing.

Comment: FYI - This method doesn't work on more than 1 machine. If you reset the same stored value on the same computer, it works fine. However, if you use that value on another computer, Edge prompts with a message stating the settings are corrupted, and were reset.

Comment: @NinjaMid76: Thanks for this hint. You are right. It works on one machine only. If I use it on a different Installation it does NOT work:-(

Answer (score -1):

1. Disable your computer's network interface
2. Launch MS Edge. The recovery page will error out
3. Open a new MS Edge tab
4. Close the MS Edge tab containing the error message
5. Close MS Edge
6. Enable your computer's network interface
7. Launch MS Edge

Comment: Easy and efficient!

Answer (score -2):

Also...

Some malware will change the Edge homepage.  You can see the malicious URL in address bar, record it.

Kill Edge with Task Manager or reboot.

Edit your hosts file in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc, from an Administrative command prompt go to that directory and type notepad hosts and hit Enter.

Add a host entry like this
127.0.0.1  bad.url  (substitute the URL you recorded above for bad.url)

Save the hosts file then open Edge.  This method is helpful when you are remoted in and cannot disconnect the network connection.

Answer (score -4):

No need to do it in registry. You can now change the homepage via the settings in Microsoft Edge

Comment: I want do it in registry because i want copy homepage from Chrome or IE ..to Edge Browser by my application..help me!!!

Comment: @QuangVuLinh you can't do it in the registry for now. Some websites will be detected as incompatible with Edge and will be routed to IE. Microsoft Edge is highly compatible with sites built for the modern Web. Internet Explorer will load automatically when Windows detects that a site requires legacy technologies that are only supported by Internet Explorer.

Comment: @quang-vu-linh was this helpful ?

Comment: I have developed an aplication and i want to change homepage of Edge Browser..If you know another way change by C#..please help me!! thank