# Is there a way to to set Microsoft Edge browser's default URL programatically like we do for IE

Tags: microsoft-edge

Is there a way to to set Microsoft Edge browser's default URL programatically like we do for IE.
We can create a batch file and set the defaults home page in IE but I am unable to do so in Microsoft edge. Can any one help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change homepage by Registry in Edge Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769921/how-to-change-homepage-by-registry-in-edge-browser)

Comment: hi, This URL doesn't answer my questions. I just wanted to know like the way we change IE browser settings through a batch file command. Is there to way to work the same thing in Microsoft Edge browser